# Query either field with highest number

Tags: mysql, database, field

I have 2 fields in a database table: "up" and "down" and they both have integer values.

```
up = 8
down = 4
```

To pull rows where up is more than down I use

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE up > down";
```

Suppose I want to pull the value of either field that has the highest number. How would I do this in a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT IF(a > b, a, b) AS max_value
  FROM (SELECT MAX(up) AS a,
               MAX(down) AS b
          FROM table) x
```

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't `SELECT GREATEST( up, down ) FROM table` be simpler? (just found out about it)

Comment: @Noob: Does it work? ;-) You could replace only mine `IF` with `SELECT GREATEST(up, down)`, yes.

Comment: @Noob: I can't believe that your query returns only one row.

Comment: @Noob: oh, wait, do you need to get the greatest value for each row?!?!? If so - I just misunderstood you. I thought you need the 1 greatest value from the whole table.

Comment: It returns multiple rows. One of two fields with the greatest value for all rows. That's what I needed, perhaps I didn't explain properly.

Comment: @Noob: it's my fault, I had to write both queries then :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found that the `greatest()` function is ideal for my case http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest

```
SELECT GREATEST( up, down ) FROM table
```